# Is there a way to get directory path from FileDialog in Java?

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt

I'm building a simple program in Java and I'm new to the GUI in general. I'm trying to open a FileDialog to select a Directory and use it's path to send a file to the selected directory. However, it does not work with the FileDialog.

Now, I tried the JFileChooser and it keeps hanging and does not display the full Mac OS X dialog the way FileDialog does it and I would prefer using the latter. Below is the code for my FileDialog. How can I get the selected directory and print it out when I select it from the dialog? I spent 2 days researching, I just can't find a good solution that works and shows the full MAC OS X dialog.

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
File selectedPath = null;
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
if (osName.equals("Mac OS X")) {
    System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.setDirectory(homeDir);
    fd.setVisible(true);
    String filename = fd.getDirectory();
    selectedPath = new File(filename);

    if (filename == null) {
        continue;
    } else {
        save_location = filename;
        dout.writeUTF("200"); //Status OK
        dout.flush();
        System.out.println(filename);
    }               
    System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the selected directory and print it out when I select it
>   from the dialog?

Use `fd.getFile()` to get the name of the directory .e.g.

```
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File selectedPath = null;
        if (osName.equals("Mac OS X")) {
            System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
            FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
            fd.setDirectory(homeDir);
            fd.setVisible(true);
            String fileName = fd.getFile();
            System.out.println(fileName);
            File file;
            if (fileName != null) {
                file = new File(fd.getDirectory() + fileName);
                System.out.println("You selected "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("You haven't selected anything");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** when I select `Desktop` and then press `Open`

```
Desktop
You selected /Users/arvind.avinash/Desktop
```

**Notes:**

1. Use `fd.getDirectory()` to get the path of the parent of the selected directory i.e. `/Users/arvind.avinash/` in my example.
2. Use `fd.getFile()` to get the name of the selected directory i.e. `Desktop` in my example.
3. Use combined `fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile()` to get the full path of the selected  directory i.e. `/Users/arvind.avinash/Desktop` in my example.

Comment: Aren't you getting the result the way I have mentioned? Please let me know what is not working.

Comment: Although it does return the location, I get an IOException error just after because I'm moving a file to that place. If you look at my code in OP, this is what I'm trying to do if the if/else statement

Comment: I do not know what `dout` refers to and therefore, I can't help with it unless I've more/complete code.

Comment: dout is similar to System.out.println, except this one is writing the message to a socket to the Server. So, you can literally think of it as Sysout.

Comment: You have written `save_location = filename;` - is this the code you are referring to? What's `save_location`? I'm also not able to understand it as you are not writing anything to `save_location`.

Comment: save_location is just a string which I have defined. This is what needs to hold the path of the directory once I select it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add some more code. Let me know if it helps solve your problem.

Comment: This one works partially. However, I'm limited to the Home directory. So let's say for example, I choose another directory, say Downloads in the left side bar, it will output it's a file. Try it out and you will see. If it's not a folder in the user.home, it doesn't work.

Comment: @nTuply - I've updated my answer again and now it works for all cases. I hope, it helps.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much. Could you maybe add a bit of explanation in your answer? I believe this could help a lot of people in the future.